# Modified Douglas-Peucker (TD-TR) implementation

Tags: algorithm

Douglas-Peucker algorithm is a line generalization algorithm, that recursively selects points from the original set of GPS trajectory points.

But this algorithm is not suitable for GPS trajectory data since both spatial and temporal data should be taken into account, while DP only takes into acount the spatial predicates.

There are several DP implementations like:

1) https://pypi.org/project/rdp/

2) https://rdp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

In order to take into acount the temporal extent, there is another algorithm called Modified Douglas-Peucker (TD-TR). The TD-TR approach uses the DP algorithm and, moreover, takes **time** into account. In particular, it replaces the Euclidean distance used in DP by a time-aware one, called Synchronous Euclidean Distance (SED).

I wonder if there some implementation of this algorithm.

Comment: The Douglas-Peucker algorithm reduces the number of points in a track by omitting points which are most far off in terms of perpendicular distance. Therefore, every remaining point belongs to the original track and has its original time information. Why should it be necessary to recompute/modify the temporal data? Could you include a link to the mentioned TD-TR paper?

Comment: Thank you @AxelKemper for the response. Please take a look at: http://www.cs.albany.edu/tech-reports/2010/SUNYA-CS-10-06.pdf .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [original paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4c4d/8b60e95b58a66b303f45b8f42c5c5ba4d585.pdf) (*Spatiotemporal Compression Techniques for Moving Point Objects* by Nirvana Meratnia and Rolf A. de By) contains pseudo code for the enhanced algorithm which imposes a limit on distance error as well as speed error for trajectory compression. This is relevant because the reduction of track points might cause errors in the observed speed.

A Python implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/ruipgil/TrackToTrip/blob/master/tracktotrip/compression.py).

Comment: In my case i care only about the spatio-temporal predicates and not the speed. So after your comment in my question above I am little confused. Why someone needs to use the TD-TR algorithm as far as "every remaining point belongs to the original track and has its original time information. Why should it be necessary to recompute/modify the temporal data?"

Comment: The time information is exact vor each of the original points. However, the moving speed (calculated as location distance divided by time difference) is not. If you are just interested in the times and locations, you could use the standard algorithm and keep the times.

Comment: Yes, you could modify a standard Douglas-Peucker code. If you store all data in `Waypoint` objects, the time information stays available right away.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to obtain straight sections with a constant speed, doesn't that reduce to finding straight sections in the 4D representation (x, y, z, t), using standard DP ?